# "Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production" even though I'm in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the full error:

```
Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( tutorial.js )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
```

When the server starts up, it say that it's in development:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.7 application starting in development
```

Comment: as suggested in the error do this - Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( tutorial.js )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server

Comment: So every single JS file has to be referenced here? Seems like a pretty hacky solution.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes clearing the tmp can help. `rake tmp:clear`

Comment: That did the trick for me, thanks!  Does anyone have an explanation for how leftwover temp files could cause such a fatal error? Sprockets should really be made more robust than that...